# Iterating a va_list when passed as a parameter to a method in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, variadic-functions

I would like to pass a variable argument list from one method (functionOne) to another (functionTwo).  Everything works fine, except that I have not been able to figure out how to setup the va_list in functionTwo in a way where I can access the first parameter in the va_list.  Using va_arg advances to the second parameter in the va_list.  Thx.

```
- (void)functionOne:(NSString *)configFiles, ... {
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, configFiles);
    [self functionTwo:args];
    va_end(args);
}

- (void)functionTwo:(va_list)files {
    NSString *file;
    while ((file = va_arg(configFiles, NSString *))) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that `functions` in object-oriented programming languages (like Objective-C) are called `methods`!

Comment: @HAS: There are _both_ functions _and_ methods in ObjC. The procedures in the question are indeed methods, but that doesn't mean functions don't exist.

Comment: @JoshCaswell Thank you for the correction. I knew that we can use plain old c functions in Objective-C as well (there are no Objective-C-only functions, are there?). My comment is indeed incorrect, I don't know why I wrote it like that ... thanks again :)

Comment: @HAS: No problem; I've often written comments myself that I see later and wonder what I was thinking to have phrased them so strangely.

Comment: Ya, sorry about the terminology error.  Sloppy post.  I'll leave it as a good answer has been provided which references code from the original post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first **variadic** argument is not the argument passed to `va_start` – it's the one immediately following it. If you want `functionTwo:` to have access to the `configFiles` string, you'll need to pass it in explicitly.

Answer (score 2):

See [Technical Q&A QA1405: Variable arguments in Objective-C methods](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#qa/qa1405/_index.html).

> Methods that take variable arguments are known as variadic methods.
>
> Keep in mind that the implementation of an Objective-C method is just
>   a block of code, like a C function. The variadic argument macros
>   described in the stdarg(3) manual page work the same way in a method
>   as they do in an ordinary function.
>
> Here's an example of an Objective-C category, containing a variadic
>   method that appends all the objects in a nil-terminated list of
>   arguments to an NSMutableArray instance:

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

@interface NSMutableArray (variadicMethodExample)

// This method takes a nil-terminated list of objects.
- (void)appendObjects:(id)firstObject, ...;

@end

@implementation NSMutableArray (variadicMethodExample)

- (void)appendObjects:(id)firstObject, ... {
    id eachObject;
    va_list argumentList;
    if (firstObject) // The first argument isn't part of the varargs list,
        {                                   // so we'll handle it separately.
      [self addObject: firstObject];
      // Start scanning for arguments after firstObject.
      va_start(argumentList, firstObject);
      while (eachObject = va_arg(argumentList, id)) // As many times as we can get an argument of type "id"
      [self addObject: eachObject]; // that isn't nil, add it to self's contents.
      va_end(argumentList);
    }
}

@end
```

Comment: I saw that code sample in QA1405, too, but I don't think it's valid. It seems to assume that `va_arg` returns `nil` when done, but it doesn't. The `va_arg` documentation says, "If there is no next argument, or if type is not compatible with the type of the actual next argument (as promoted according to the default argument promotions), random errors will occur.".

Comment: @Rob as I understand it, it will work if the list is nil-terminated.

Answer (score 2):

A solution that I use for debugging purposes is like

```
-(void) debug:(NSString*)format, ... {

    if (level < MXMLogLevelDebug) return;

    if(format == nil) return;

    va_list args, args_copy;
    va_start(args, format);
    va_copy(args_copy, args);
    va_end(args);

    NSString *logString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:format
                                                  arguments:args_copy];

    NSString *funcCaller = @"";
    NSArray *syms = [NSThread  callStackSymbols];
    if ([syms count] > 1) {
        funcCaller = [syms objectAtIndex:1];
    }
    NSString *logMessage = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ DEBUG: %@", funcCaller, logString];

    NSLog(@"%@",logMessage);


}
```

The side-effect that this can have is that you have to add a guard on the args to be sure is not NULL.